# Entity not visible in swagger UI api platform

Tags: php, symfony, entity, api-platform.com

I use Api Platform & Symfony (5.4) + php 7.2.5

I created an Entity by myself, I just added one file in /src/Entity and it's not working.

I refresh, I cleared cache, I adde @ApiResource... But the Entity is not visible in the doc page in API Platform.

Have you an idea where the error is ?
Thanks !

Here is the code I used for the new entity :

```
// api/src/Entity/Review.php

namespace App\Entity;

use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;

/** A review of a book. */
/** 
* @ApiResource()
*/
class Review
{
    /** The id of this review. */
    private ?int $id = null;

    /** The rating of this review (between 0 and 5). */
    public int $rating = 0;

    /** The body of the review. */
    public string $body = '';

    /** The author of the review. */
    public string $author = '';

    /** The date of publication of this review.*/
    public ?\DateTimeInterface $publicationDate = null;

    /** The book this review is about. */
    public ?Book $book = null;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have this in the config file :

 mapping:
        paths: ['%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity']

Comment: The only way to display my entity is to create a file in in /Repository but my entity is not related to doctrine or database...

Comment: It is very difficult to tell the cause of the problem, since it is impossible to repeat your problem. Publish the project to a public repository so we can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should delete your Entity and remake it with the cmd :

```
php bin/console make:entity
```

that will make a Rewiew.php files in Entity folders with getter and setter and correct annotations examples :

```
 /**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100, nullable=true)
 */
```

and repository file etc..
dont forget use :

php bin/console make:migration

and:

php bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate

for update your database. And dont forget to use apiplatform annotation.
I think actually the bundle can't know how use your entity because of missing information

Comment: Yeah I did this, I also think there was a problem with annotations : it changed when I added line-breaks instead of having parameters on the same line : 
{param:1,param2:param3}

{
param:1,
param:2
param : 3
}

Answer (score 5):

try replacing this

- `use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;`

with this

- `use ApiPlatform\Metadata\ApiResource;`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).